# Persistir sessão mesmo após o servidor crashar e subir novamente em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

Como faço para persistir a sessão de login do usuário mesmo quando a aplicação "crasha" e volta novamente. Atualmente quando o servidor da algum erro inesperado eu vou lá arrumo o erro e salvo, ai o servidor reinicia e a sessão do usuário morre ou até mesmo quando a aplicação crasha e reinicia sozinha.

Quero algo similar ao artisan do laravel...que quando salvo algo no php ele reinicia o server mas não apaga as sessões.

Comment: Se você reiniciar o servidor, irá perder a memória volátil. Para persistir a sessão depois que o servidor reiniciar, você precisa gravar a sessão numa memória não volátil. MemCached, Redis e até mesmo MongoDB são bastante utilizados para cashing.

Comment: Valeu estou pesquisando aqui mas ajudou muito valeu! XD